# Which permission is needed to see rejected page versions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, content-approval

I have a Page Library with enabled Content Approval.
Basically three different user groups with Standard Permission Level "Approver", "Contribute" and "View Only".
View Only Users cannot see rejected page versions, Contributors can.

Which checkbox in the permissions controls the visibility of rejected versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rejected page versions are draft items. You can set permissions of Draft items
in Library settings-> Versioning Settings-> Draft Item Security.

[image]